# Filter data from datatable for one of columns in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, filter, datatable

I have a `datatable` which fetches some records. So there is one column name as **UPDATED_STATUS**. In that column either `Pre Hoto` or `Post Hoto` value will come.

So what I want is, Either any one of those values should be their in that column then only the it should move ahead otherwise it should prompt alert as

**Either Pre Hoto or Post Hoto can be their**

Below is sample image for reference

[image: IMG]

Below is the code for getting the `datatable` with the `UPDATED_STATUS` column

```
if (strFlag == "")
                    {
                        dtStatus = GET_STATUS_FROM_SAPID_FOR_HOTO(dtExcelRows.Rows[i]["Current SAPID"].ToString());

                        if (dtStatus == null && dtStatus.Rows.Count < 0)
                        {
                            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "erroralert", "alert('Status cannot be blank for SAP ID entered');", true);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dtExcelRows.Rows[i]["UPDATED_STATUS"] = dtStatus.Rows[0][1].ToString();
                            dtExcelRows.AcceptChanges();
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: change (dtStatus == null || dtStatus.Rows.Count == 0 to (dtStatus == null && dtStatus.Rows.Count < 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got a way to get this done.. Here I go

```
if (strFlag == "")
                    {
                        dtStatus = GET_STATUS_FROM_SAPID_FOR_HOTO(dtExcelRows.Rows[i]["Current SAPID"].ToString());

                        if (dtStatus == null && dtStatus.Rows.Count < 0)
                        {
                            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "erroralert", "alert('Status cannot be blank for SAP ID entered');", true);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dtExcelRows.Rows[i]["UPDATED_STATUS"] = dtStatus.Rows[0][1].ToString();
                            dtExcelRows.AcceptChanges();
                        }
                    }
                }

                DataTable dtGetHotoPre = null;
                var rows = dtExcelRows.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("UPDATED_STATUS") == "PRE HOTO");

                if (rows.Any())
                {
                    dtGetHotoPre = rows.CopyToDataTable();
                }

                DataTable dtGetHotoPost = null;
                var rowsPost = dtExcelRows.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("UPDATED_STATUS") == "POST HOTO");

                if (rowsPost.Any())
                {
                    dtGetHotoPost = rowsPost.CopyToDataTable();
                }
                string strFlagStatus = "";
                if (dtGetHotoPre != null)
                {
                    if (dtGetHotoPost != null)
                    {
                        strFlagStatus = "No Process";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        strFlagStatus = "Process";
                        grdDvHoto.DataSource = dtGetHotoPost;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (dtGetHotoPost != null)
                    {
                        strFlagStatus = "Process";
                        grdDvHoto.DataSource = dtGetHotoPre;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        strFlagStatus = "No Process";
                    }
                }

               // if(dtGetHotoPre != null && dtGetHotoPost != null)

                if (strFlagStatus == "No Process")
                {
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "erroralert", "alert('The sites contains both Pre and Post Hoto Status, so it cannot be uploaded');", true);
                }
                else 
                {
                    // will move ahead.                        
                    grdDvHoto.DataBind();
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current check (`if (dtStatus == null && dtStatus.Rows.Count < 0)`) is wrong:

1. when dtStatus is null, you continue checking dtStatus.Rows, which throws a nullref exception (you just found out that it was null);
2. Rows.Count is never less than zero.

Try `if (dtStatus == null || dtStatus.Rows.Count == 0)` to check whether there is no status at all (it is `null`) or no status rows (count is zero). The `||` will prevent checking for dtStatus.Rows when it was found that dtStatus is null.

`&&` means that both sides must be `true` at the same time.
`||` means that at least of the sides must be true (both true is also fine).
Both don't evaluate the second test when the first already decided the outcome (false && whatever is always false, true || whatever is always true)

Comment: which code you are talking about.. my answer part or my question ?

Comment: In the question, but now I see it is in your answer too

Comment: ohh, I m still confused with what is wrong.. can u update my answer code and put up a new answer. so that I can debug and verify. Let me know in case if you need anything from me

Comment: Just replace what I marked as "your current check" and replace with the "Try". It is the third code-line in your samples

Comment: Thanks Hans, updated my code. upvoted too for your guide

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for like this !

```
foreach (DataRow row in dtStatus.Rows)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(row["UPDATED_STATUS"])) || 
     (Convert.ToString(row["UPDATED_STATUS"]).ToLower() != "pre hoto" && 
     Convert.ToString(row["UPDATED_STATUS"]).ToLower() != "post hoto"))
     {
          ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "erroralert", "alert('Status cannot be blank for SAP ID entered');", true);
          break;
     }
     else { }
}
```

Comment: I use DataRows loop for checking condition

Comment: its not working. always going in else even if the status is same